# Handle async operation in Java

Tags: java, asynchronous, concurrency, vert.x

Problem with below code is, if I remove `Thread.sleep(1000);` then I get inconsistent result. I don't want to use `Thread.Sleep(1000);`
As I am using async operation of vertx, I want to wait till my rowSet is filled up with data.

Please help
Thanks in advance...!

```
import io.vertx.pgclient.RgPool;
import io.vertx.sqlclient.Row;
import io.vertx.sqlclient.RowSet;

class TestAsyncOperation{
private RowSet<Row> rowSet;

public RowSet<Row> getResult(){

   PgPool conn = DbConfig.getConnection();// consider db connections is received

   String qry = "select col1 as column1, col2 as column2 from SomeTable";
   
   conn.query(qry).execute(asyncResult -> {
       if(asyncResult.succeeded()){
         rowSet = asyncResult.result();
       }else{
           throw new Exception(asyncResult.cause().getMessage());
       }
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    if(Optional.ofNullable(rowSet).isPresent){
       return rowSet;
     }else{
       return null;
     }

});

}

}
```

Comment: What you're doing isn't asynchronous, so there's no real need to use the asynchronous operation.

Comment: what is io.vertx.pgclient.RgPool? It could not be find in maven central.

Comment: `if(Optional.ofNullable(rowSet).isPresent) { return rowSet; }else{ return null; }` is (letting the missing `()` aside) an obfuscated way to achieve exactly the same as `return rowSet;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java Future feature to handle the result only when it's done, but if you are using vertx method `executeBlocking` that can run inside the eventLoop but it needs to be a low seconds task, you can use a worker verticle that use a whole thread just for a verticle, IMO you should consider a reactive approach, using the reactive lib RxJava from java 9 you can subscribe to your dabatase change and do your work, vert.x offers a Rxjava plugin btw.

Answer (score 0):

For communications between parallel activities (threads and asynchronous procedures), simple variables do not fit.
Instead, dataflow variables should be used, e.g. Futures:

```
    PgPool conn = DbConfig.getConnection();// consider db connections is received
    String qry = "select col1 as column1, col2 as column2 from SomeTable";
    CompletableFuture<RowSet<Row>> rowSet = new CompletableFuture<RowSet<Row>>();
    conn.query(qry).execute(asyncResult -> {
        if(asyncResult.succeeded()){
            rowSet.complete(asyncResult.result());
        }else{
            rowSet.completeExceptionally(asyncResult.cause());
        }
    });
    try {
        return rowSet.get();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: I’m not using this framework, but from the recognizable pattern, I’d make the educated guess, that the whole point of the callback style processing is that the framework will handle the resource management, i.e. that the `RowSet` will be closed when the callback returns. So using a callback that stores the resource in an external object is defeating the purpose of the API (and will likely break).